# Converting PetaPoco.Database.LastCommand to a SQL command to run in a Query window

Tags: sql-server, petapoco

For debugging purposes, I would like to be able to see what SQL PetaPoco is attempting to run on the databse (so that I can copy-paste it into a query window and see the results).  Using Database.LastCommand, I get output like this (though generally much longer with a lot of variables):

```
SELECT * FROM tWidgets WHERE WidgetID=@0
    -> @0 [Int32] = "2"
```

Is there an easy way to convert this to a format that will run in SQLServer?

Comment: Configure logging or use SQL Server's Profiler to see exactly what gets executed

Answer (score 0):

PetaPoco do not run the query with all the parameters, it merely pass the statements and parameters to ADO.net. ADO will then run the query.

I would like also to have a quick and dirty way to get the last command with all the params instanciated that you can easily copy to Sql Server to test